# Using FormData.append() throws error

Tags: react-native, redux, fetch, redux-saga

Within my `redux-saga` I am making a fetch call that requires formdata as the body.

```
const formdata = new FormData();
var blob = new Blob(['test'],{})
formdata.append('file', blob);
```

However this throws the error

```
TypeError: One of the sources for assign has an enumerable key on the prototype chain. Are you trying to assign a prototype property? We don't allow it, as this is an edge case that we do not support. This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant.
    at Object.assign (Object.es6.js:55)
    at FormData.js:81
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at FormData.getParts (FormData.js:65)
    at convertRequestBody (convertRequestBody.js:31)
    at RCTNetworking.sendRequest (RCTNetworking.ios.js:39)
    at XMLHttpRequest.send (XMLHttpRequest.js:495)
    at fetch.js:462
    at tryCallTwo (core.js:45)
    at doResolve (core.js:200)
```

This has happened on two other packages I have also attempted to use to solve this same problem. Has anyone come across this before or knows a work around? I couldn't find a lot of info on this error.

Comment: perhaps this might put some light to the problem, [React-native - Populate image with Blob that has been converted to a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786566/2315280)

Comment: Thank you so much, this has put me on the right path