# Get PDF out of arraybuffer in React Native

Tags: react-native, blob, fetch, arraybuffer

The websocket on my server sends my react-native app an arraybuffer of a PDF and from there I'm trying to figure out how to display the PDF. I feel like `rn-fetch-blob` would be the answer but I'm not sure what goes where. On the browser, I just did this:

```
const pdfBlob = new Blob([e.data], {type: "application/pdf"})
const url = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
pdfViewer.setAttribute("src", url)
```

But React Native doesn't support making Blobs like that. My next attempt was doing something like this:

```
fetch(e.data, {
  responseType: "arraybuffer"
})
  .then(res => res.arrayBuffer())
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(pdfBlob => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
    /** ... */
  })
  .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

But that didn't work either. I know [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38506971/react-native-populate-image-with-blob-that-has-been-converted-to-a-url) got it working for images when his response from the server was a blob, but I don't know if it's the same thing.

I'm still super shakey on arraybuffers, blobs, fetching, etc. so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have you found a solution is this

Comment: @Gokul check my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mmm this was a while ago so I'm not super sure about my own code or if it's already out of date. I remember reading something about RNFetchBlob being unnecessary with newer versions of React but here's how I did it:

```
import RNFetchBlob from "rn-fetch-blob";
const { fs } = RNFetchBlob;

connection.onmessage = e => {
  if (typeof e.data === "string") {
    /* not array buffer */
  } else if (e.data.constructor === ArrayBuffer) {
    const base64 = binaryToBase64(e.data);
    const filePath = `${fs.dirs.CacheDir}/${shortid.generate()}.pdf`;

    RNFetchBlob.fs.createFile(filePath, base64, "base64").then(path => {
      // necessary ?
      RNFetchBlob.session("all").add(path);
    });
  }
};
```

I think I added the path to the `session` so I could delete the pdfs in bulk later on by their session id. Otherwise, I think with that path you can just pass that into the PDF component like this:

```
<Pdf source={{ uri: path, cache: false }} />
```

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the exact same solution, it works.

Comment: i am using expo so may i use "rn-fetch-blob" to download file?