# How to create File or Blob from Uri in React Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, npm

I am using expo-image-picker to select image from device and I need to upload it to Firebase Storage.
How can I create a File or Blob from uri?

This is the object I receive when selecting the image:

> Object {
> "cancelled": false,
> "height": 1600,
> "type": "image",
> "uri": "file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/test-app/ImagePicker/27aef7c8-3317-4980-a443-249fdc0b7096.jpg",
> "width": 900,
> }

Comment: Have you tried `apollo-upload-client`? as I'm a big fan of GraphQL and Apollo-GraphQL I have always use this one.

Comment: No I haven't. I'll try this.

Comment: Forget about that if you are not using a GraphQL server, try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786566/11449703) instead. This will suit your usecase.

Comment: Thank you. I solved this issue using `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Glad to hear that, good luck ;)